# Is it bad practice to put sprites under a canvas?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I make 2D games, I always attach the sprites under a canvas so that I can set the canvas scaling to be "Scale With Screen Size" so that the sprites scale with the users aspect ratio. Is this bad practice and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You are correct to do so.

Answer (score 3):

Unity shouldn't render objects off-screen, so in realtime there shouldn't be any problems with graphics performance.
From personal experience, making a game responsive for different resolutions is complicated and many techniques can be used to get good results.
I also use the "Scale with screen size" setting, and over the years I haven't found anything that works better.
The only detail I can give you for general performance: if you have many elements, perhaps animated, and they are not seen at all by the camera, I recommend that you disable them from scripts, because graphically they should not give problems, but they are always things that the engine calculates frame by frame and therefore if they are not essential it is better to disable them.